# Django - New object is not created if html action argument is provided

Tags: python, html, django

I have simple contact form:

```html
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form_email.as_div }}
  {{ form_message.as_div }}
  <button name="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

When text is provided in both fields (email and message) and then the user click on submit button, the data should be saved in data base.

**View function:**

```
def index(request):
    """The home page."""

    # Send a message.
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form_email = EmailForm()
        form_message = EmailMessageForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; proecess data.
        form_email = EmailForm(data=request.POST)
        form_message = EmailMessageForm(data=request.POST)
        if form_email.is_valid() and form_message.is_valid():
            form_email.save()
            email = Email.objects.last()
            message = form_message.save(commit=False)
            message.email = email
            message.save()

    # Display a blank or invalid form.
    context = {'form_email': form_email, 'form_message': form_message}
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', context)
```

Until now everything works as expected, but when I add action argument in order to redirect the user to the 'Thank you' page if form has been sent, the data is not saved.

```html
<form action="{% url 'home:contact_thank_you' %}" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form_email.as_div }}
     {{ form_message.as_div }}
     <button name="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Do you have any idea why the data is not saved when I add the action argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem. I added redirect() function in view function:

```
return redirect('home:contact_thank_you')
```